# Uri to open third party apps for wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I tried to create an app that opens some third party apps with the help of its Uri from a Tile. Well, it actually works in opening the third party apps but the problem is, first it launches my app(i.e **MainPage is visible for a second**) and then only it opens the respective app. Is there any way to make my app's MainPage invisible before opening an app or am i missing anything in Capabilities?

Here is my code :

```
        IconicTileData iconicTileData1 = new IconicTileData();
        iconicTileData1.Title = name;
        iconicTileData1.SmallIconImage = new Uri("/Icons/Small.png", UriKind.Relative);
        iconicTileData1.IconImage = new Uri("/Icons/Metro/" + name + "Medium.png", UriKind.Relative);
        IconicTileData iconicTileData2 = iconicTileData1;
        Uri navigationUri = new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?target=ms-settings-bluetooth:", UriKind.Relative);
        ShellTile.Create(navigationUri, (ShellTileData)iconicTileData2, true);
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You need to provide your code. How else could anyone diagnose this problem

Comment: @AnthonyRussell Sorry, i thought i posted my code already. Edited the post, please take a look.

Comment: Have you tried making the URI without the /MainPage.xaml ?

Comment: Yeah, but it throws an error.

Comment: How are you navigating to the third party app is my real question. Are you grabbing that target param and launching it from within your app?

Comment: Yes, am using it in MainPage_Loaded() , Code is `this.NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("target", out uriString);`
`Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(uriString));`

Comment: Try donig it on the OnNavigatedTo event of the page, instead of the Loaded event.

Comment: @yasen This is weird now. For some apps, it opens the app then MainPage of my app and then the respective app starts and for some apps, it works correctly. But for bluetooth kind of tile, its still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to specify a "custom" page target (instead of MainPage.xaml) and then make a UriMapper that will allow your app to redirect. Here is a nice [blog post on creating a UriMapper](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2012/06/18/Using-a-custom-UriMapper-to-navigate-to-a-login-screen.aspx). Here is some pseudo-code to help:

```
public class SettingsUriMapper : UriMapperBase
{
    public override Uri MapUri(Uri uri)
    {
        if (uri.OriginalString.StartsWith == "/LaunchSettings.xaml")
        {
            // parse which settings to go to
            // launch settings uri
        }
        return uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try this as soon as possible. Thanks!